Unable to connect to GCS Bucket using hadoop-connector over WIF
Getting bellow error while connecting to GCS with Hadoop
Error reading credentials from stream, 'type' value 'external_account' not recognized. Expecting 'authorized_user' or 'service_account'

I am using WIF for GCS Service Account authorization.
Check the code for hadoop-connector - Seems this error is not really coming from GoogleCredential class, but somewhere else. I have written a Java App which is successfully connecting to GCS bucket with same credential.
GCS Hadoop-Connector Version: 2.1.0.
Can anyone help me with this?

Make sure the GCS Hadoop Connector version you're using is relevant and supports external_account. Refer to the Github document on Building the Cloud Storage connector for more information.

Note that build requires Java 11+ and fails with older Java versions.
To build the connector for a specific Hadoop version, run the following commands from the main directory: ./mvnw clean package
In order to verify test coverage for specific Hadoop versions, run the following commands from the main directory: ./mvnw -P coverage clean verify
The Cloud Storage connector JAR can be found in gcs/target/ directory.

Also refer to these similar Github issue1 and issue2 for additional details.
